# iOS app rejected due to not being able to be downloaded

Tags: ios, iphone

my app was recently rejected, below is Apple's response.

----- 2.2 -----

We found that your app exhibited one or more bugs, when reviewed on iPad running iOS 8.1 and iPhone 5s running iOS 8.1, on both Wi-Fi and cellular networks, which is not in compliance with the App Store Review Guidelines.

Specifically, the app will not download on a device.

---

Could anyone point me in the right way in what exactly this means and how I can fix this bug? I have installed my .ipa file to several devices (included an iPhone 5s) and they all worked correctly.

Thanks

Comment: Ask them for details. They're not robots; they'll answer questions if you ask nicely.

Comment: I don't even. The only thing I can think of is to check your device requirements. You might have an empty key in info.plist that prevents your app from installing everywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can check your **Deployment Target** in your project **build settings**. If its greater then 8.1 or higher then instead of that put 7.0 and check in all device.

It may that you submitted IPA or binary with deployment version greater then 8.1 or higher and they check in device which contains OS less than your deployment target so its not allowed you to install the app.